# Android - SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Tags: java, android

I have the following layout (virtually empty):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/set_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="content desc"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Activity class contains the following:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);   
  }
}
```

When I run this on my mobile device I get the following error:

```
SpannableStringBuilder
SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

I have tried this with and without the TextView and the error still remains, I must be doing something fundamentally wrong for such a basic layout to cause this.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to load without the error?

Comment: Examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your error. If it indeed is from this app, post the entire stack trace as an edit to your question. Also, I would get rid of `android:contentDescription` from `LinearLayout`, as that container is not focusable and therefore the description will not be used AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately there is no stack trace for this error, the output is exactly as i have posted above, but the application field in LogCat does point to my application. I have debugged the code and stepped through each line with no error being thrown, so it must be somewhere in the Android code that is expecting something that isn't there.

Comment: I would like to know how to avoid this annoying error too, without removing/disabling any feature for the end user.

Comment: I reset the phone to factory settings and it went away, after trying the 'samsung keyboard fix' which didn't seem to do the trick for me...

Comment: Perhaps it isn't a problem at all, but after upgrading to Android 4.1.1 I'm seeing a lot of errors in the logs like this one.
SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Comment: I only get this error on a Pixel running Android P so it might be something Google still needs to iron out.

Answer (score 253):

I have run into the same error entries in LogCat. In my case it's caused by the 3rd party keyboard I am using. When I change it back to Android keyboard, the error entry does not show up any more.

Comment: thanks @Rabi, even i switched to swiftkey and started getting the errror.

Comment: I get the error while using stock Android keyboard on a Nexus 7 (2012 edition, running 4.3)

Comment: (On Galaxy S4, 4.4.2) -- Switching back to the stock samsung keyboard fixed this for me. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately the link from @Rabi above isn't good anymore. But thank you for this. I am indeed using SwiftKey and it appears to still be causing this issue 2 years later.

Comment: There isn't event an `EditText`-view in the layout shown in the question, so I don't get how can it be related to input and the keyboard. I believe the problem is caused by some layout-related bug in Samsung's TouchWiz, because I'm getting the same error as in the question when I test my app on my Samsung device, and any `TextView` is updated, due to screen rotation or something alike. I would be happy if the error could go away, but until I find a solution, I guess I will live with it...

Comment: This issue appears with Gboard(!) as well (and it's from Google)

Answer (score 117):

Because the error you're getting is **not** related to an `EditText`, then it's **not** related to your keyboard.

The errors you are getting are not a result of your code; you probably are testing on a Samsung device that has Samsung's TouchWiz.

I had the same errors, then I tested on a Nexus S (also by Samsung, but pure Android OS without TouchWiz) and I didn't get this error.

So, in your case, just ignore these errors while testing on a device! :)

Comment: It is your keyboard, probably the keyboard of TouchWiz in your case. I have the same errors on a Nexus 4 with Swiftkey, if I choose the default Android keyboard the errors are gone.

Comment: Keyboards can definitely lead to this error, but in the case where the keyboard is not used or called, i.e. in the case where there are no EditText's, I don't see how the keyboard can be the source of the problem. When I switch between two different activities, both without EditText, I keep getting the error every time I go to one of these activities.

Comment: I agree with Cookiki, the errors are because of Samsung TouchWiz, and its not causing any problems other than spewing errors in logcat. So will be ignoring them

Comment: We can't just ignore errors because it only happens on a TouchWiz, the least is reporting to samsung that there's a problem with touchwiz.

Comment: I can most certainly occur without it being related to an EditText. I had this error when displaying a PreferenceFragment with some headers - no textboxes or anything of the sort. On every change from one PreferenceFragment I got two of these error messages. Switched from "Samsung Keyboard" to "Smart Keyboard Pro" and the error messages stopped.

Comment: The error **still appears** when running **Cyanogenmod 11** on a samsung device _(Samsung Galaxy S3)_

Comment: Same problem here, only on the Samsung devices we have.

Comment: same issue here in 10 inch acer tablet,In samsung 7 inch tab working fine.

Comment: same problem on Huawei P30 Lite

Answer (score 55):

Looking at your code, I'm not sure why you're getting that error, but I had this same error but with EditText fields.

Changing `android:inputType="text"` (or any of the other inputType text variations) to `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` (or `android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"`, for example) fixed it for me.

You can also set this in Code with something like

```
mInputField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Looks like Android assumes by default that EditText fields will have suggestions.  When they don't, it errors.  Not 100% confident in that explanation, but the above mentioned changes fixed it for me.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html#SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this. But even with the TextView removed and only the layout present i get the error. It is very strange.

Comment: Removing the contentDescription from the LinearLayout doesn't help?

Comment: No unfortunately not. Although with further investigation the error does only seem to display on Samsung Devices.

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't fix in Samsung Galaxy A51 w/ Android 11. But your explanation sounds really reasonable.

Answer (score 13):

On your android phone go to:
**settings -> application manager -> all -> samsung keyboard and then click on "clear cache"**
(delete all data collected by this application).

Comment: Wow I had 68 MB of stuff cached by that app. :O

Answer (score 10):

Try using the default Android keyboard it will disappear

Comment: how to use default keyboard.

Comment: You have to change it in phone input settings. If you didn't change it, you should have default keyboard. It's quite funny solution with that default keyboard, but it works for me.. : p

Comment: The default Android keyboard also has the problem (I have it on a Nexus 5)

Answer (score 3):

Make clear you have pass a value in your MainAcitivity for the following methods onCreateOptionsMenu and onCreate

In some cases, the developer deletes the "return  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)" statement  and changed to "return  true".

Answer (score 2):

> This worked for me...on every device

```
    <EditText
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/input_search"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Enter Address, City or Zip Code"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        />
```

In Java code:

```
mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                    || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                //execute our method for searching
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like charm

Comment: it seems having a listener is a must

Comment: Hello friends, in my screen not use any Edit text, Only use linear layout and button.i face same problem when i run app on tablet(4.1.2).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning and found that removing an unused @id got rid of the warning. For me it was obvious as the @id was associated with a growing list of textViews linked to a database, so there was a warning for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Masood Moshref is right, this error occur because the option menu of Menu is not well prepared by lacking "return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)" in onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

To try to debug this error, first go to your android terminal / console and execute this command:

```
ps | grep THE_ERROR_PID_YOU_GET_(IT_IS_A_NUMBER)
```

then if the output comes out as your app... it is your app causing the error. Try to look for empty `Strings` that you pass into the `layout`.

I had this exact same problem and it was my fault as I was passing an empty `String` into my layout. After changing the `""` to `" "` this error went away.

If you don't get your app from the console output, then it is something else causing it (probably, as others said, the android keyboard)

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue. I almost wasted almost couple of weeks to resolved this issue.
Finally I had on doubt on myself and tried to create another project by copy and paste some startup files like SplashScreen & LoginScreen.

But with the same code still i was getting **SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE**.

Then i have removed the handler code from splash screen and tried again and Wow its working.
I am not getting **SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE** issue in **logcat**.

I wondering, why it is? till the time did not get any other solution but by removing handler from splash screen it is working.

Try and update here if it is resolved or not.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have any element such as button or text view duplicated (copied twice) in the screen where this encounters. I did this unnoticed and had to face the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem too when I copied some text from the Internet. My solution is to trim the text/remove formatting before doing any further processing.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but with a listView.... i solved it because i was using a wrong R.id.listView that list View needed to have a value, in my case it was strings that i saved on listView2... so the right code was R.id.listView2

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem then i fixed it by following code!

```
  text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TextVoiceeditText); 
  text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Answer (score -1):

this error also occurs due to changed API URL. try hitting the URL you are using in postman and c if it's working properly.
rechecking the APIs solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

try avoiding use of **view** in xml design.I too had the same probem but when I removed the view. its worked perfectly.

like example:

```
             <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                   
                android:hint="Username"
                android:inputType="number"                   
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <view
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#f9d7db" />
```

also check and try changing by trial and error **android:inputType="number"** to **android:inputType="text"** or better not using it if not required .Sometimes keyboard stuck and gets error in some of the devices.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the EditText fields with inputType as **text / textCapCharacters** were casing this error. I noticed this in my logcat whenever I used backspace to completely remove the text typed in any of these fields.

The solution which worked for me was to change the inputType of those fields to **textNoSuggestions** as this was the most suited type and didn't give me any unwanted errors anymore.

Answer (score -1):

in my case i click on recent apps shortcut on my cell phone and close all apps. This solution always work for me, because this error not related to code.

Answer (score -4):

To solve this problem just add **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"** in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file which is at **..\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml** just like bellow...

[image]