# Why SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length error in some devices

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I am trying to start an Activity A having GridView as layout from an AsyncTask T. But it can not start A and shows

```
SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

error in logcat.

This is happening only in Samsung Galaxy as far as I know. Its working in Galaxy SII with 4.2.2 but not in Galaxy SIII with 4.0.4.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this will make the error go away, but it may be an inappropriate solution in some cases.

`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` or `android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"` etc.

[Android - SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length)

Answer (score 0):

Try not to call

```
Spannable.setSpan(Object, int, int, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

when your Spannable length is zero.

For example, your code should look something like this:

```
Spannable string = ...
if (string.length() != 0) string.setSpan(Object, int, int Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score -1):

When I uninstalled the facebook app from my android, the separate app I designed runs as usual. This must be a serious bug with facebook.