# SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making an application using Galaxy S3, and getting a "SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE cannot have a zero length" error. The app is working perfectly on an emulator. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - SPAN\_EXCLUSIVE\_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening when I test my apps on my devices as well. Do you have Swiftkey installed on your phone? This may shed some light on the issue, if you do.

http://support.swiftkey.net/forums/116693-2-bug-reports/suggestions/2994580-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-

Edit: See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13986224/183231

Comment: Nope I have not installed swift key. I am stuck on this error since a long time

Comment: 04-06 15:50:20.672: E/SpannableStringBuilder(27759): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length   This is the error I am getting in the log cat.