# Spinners item selected to go to a different page

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am having problems implementing a spinner into my code. Not quite sure how it works. But here is a brief idea of what I want to do. (Ex: click on the spinner and you have 2 options "page 2" and "page 3". So if you click on "page 2" it will go to page two with new content. Is there a way to accomplish that??

I also have image buttons to go to the next page and back. Just want to implement a spinner box so that you can navigate to different pages quicker.

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener  {

private MediaPlayer mp;
ImageButton button;
ImageButton button3;
ImageView imgView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    final String[] spstr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinnervalue);
    final Spinner sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> ar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,spstr);
    sp.setAdapter(ar);

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String s=((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            if(s.equals("page2"))
                startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),App2Activity.class));
            if(s.equals("page3"))
                startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(),App3Activity.class));

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });


}



public void addListenerOnButton() {



    final Context context = this;
    button3  = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    button3.setOnTouchListener(this);


    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.vanilla_twilight);




    button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

}

@Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),
                R.raw.vanilla_twilight);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
    };
    return true;
}
```

}

XML

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Logcat errors

05-22 01:32:40.058: E/SpannableStringBuilder(16206): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-22 01:32:40.058: E/SpannableStringBuilder(16206): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

resource
    
        page2
        page3

Comment: Set up 3 Activities.  e.g., AppActivity1, AppActivity2, AppActivity3.  AppActivity1 lets you choose AppActivity2 or 3, AppActivity2 lets you chose 1 or 3, etc.

Comment: I have three activities app1 app2 and app3 set up. I can navigate between those three pages easily with buttons but not sure how i would go about implementing them with the spinners.

Comment: `startActivity(new Intent(context, AppActivity2.class));`

Answer (score 1):

Use `startActivity` to open the other Activities, it requires a basic `Intent`

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        String s=((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();

        if(s.equals("page2"))
            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), AppActivity2.class));

        if(s.equals("page3"))
            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), AppActivity3.class));
    }
});
```

You're array in resources may not be set up correctly.

It should look similar to this:

```
<string-array name="spinnervalue">
    <item>page2</item>
    <item>page3</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: I updated my code. I decided to include my entire code because i tried what you posted and the spinner is still not showing up. So i figure it might be my positioning of codes?? I also included the logcat errors.

Comment: Can you post `R.array.spinnervalue`?  By the stack trace it seems like that array is empty.  Set a break-point at `final String[] spstr ...`, step forward one line and then see is `spstr` has any values or if it's null.

Comment: Or, maybe `String s` is not being assigned anything.  Although, I presume you would get a NullPointerException for that.  You can try `String s = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinnervalue)[position]`

Comment: i feel like my array might be empty how do i check that with break?

Comment: I presume you are using Eclipse, or at least some type of IDE, so just use the debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @mrres1. You should just create separate Activities for each screen (or `Fragments`) for each. `setContentView(layout)` won't do anything at is not allowed.

You could also look into implementing a Dropdown `ActionBar` ([example here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html)).

Comment: I'm still new to Android development so not quite sure what you mean when you use the word fragments. Can you briefly example that? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for that. :D

Check the links provided by @Tommy. They are good starting points.

I personally recommend [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/) though.

Comment: hey deubaka, i have three activities set up so how would i implement that into the spinner? so when i pick the option "page 3" it would go to app3. What do i replace setontentView(layout) with?

Comment: don't use `setContentView`, instead, launch it via `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class))`.

I would also suggest to use the `position`-argument combined with a switch-case, as this would be better that checking the strings literally.

Comment: can you help me figure out whats wrong now? The spinners are not showing up still.. And i get this logcat error message  "E/SpannableStringBuilder(16206): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length "

Comment: could you post your code? regarding the error, you may check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length)

Comment: my code is on the top ^ for some reason my spinner box is not even showing on the screen so it doesn't work not sure why..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to consider Fragments. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Or to easily implement it, you can use ActionBarSherlock library.
http://actionbarsherlock.com