# What is wrong in my code? 2 activity app, splash screen, webview

Tags: android, webview, splash-screen, activitynotfoundexception

Sorry, I am new to android apps. creation. I have referred pretty much all solutions but this just doesn't work...and I don't see any problem in below simple-code. My  app is simple, Load the splash screen, then load the webview. What is the problem below?

### ERROR I get is:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.wwes.EZEE/com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage}; have you declared this activity in your Manifext.xml
```

[COMMENT] Pls. Look below, I have already declared it. what's wrong?

### Files are:

1. MainActivity.java: Here I load the splashscreen image.

   ```
   package com.example.EZEE;

   import com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override 
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   //Thread for displaying the Splash Screen //
   Thread splash_screen = new Thread() {
   public void  run() {
       try {
       sleep(1000);
       } catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
       Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondPage.class);
       startActivity(i);
           }
           }
   }; splash_screen.start();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
   }
   ```
2. SecondPage.java: This loads the webview.

   ```
   package com.wwes.EZEE;
   public class SecondPage extends Activity {
   WebView browserView;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // Removed the title bare in the Application //
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_page);

   // Creation of the Webview found in the XML Layout file //
   browserView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

   // Enable Javascripts //
   browserView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

   browserView.getSettings()....
   browserView.getSettings()....
   browserView.getSettings()....

   browserView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);


   // Removed both vertical and horizontal scroll bars //
   browserView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
   browserView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
   browserView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

   // Webview Wrap //
   browserView.loadUrl("http://www.ABCDE.com");
   browserView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   view.loadUrl(url);
   return false;
   }

   });
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed()
   {   if(browserView.canGoBack())
   browserView.goBack();
   else  super.onBackPressed(); }
   ```

   }
3. activity_main.xml:

   ```
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:background="#800808"
   android:scaleType="fitStart"
   android:visibility="visible"
   android:src="@drawable/logo" />
   ```

4) activity_second_page.xml:

```
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

5) manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wwes.EZEE"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    ----------------------------------updated----------------------------------        
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.wwes.EZEERACKS.MainActivity" //// UPDATED ///
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|smallestScreenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second_page" >
    </activity>

    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: remove the <intent-filter> tag from the `secondPage` activity and tell me the result..

Comment: Can you post all of your `manifest.xml`. I need to see your package name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how come your main activity is `com.example.EZEE.MainActivity` while secondPage is `com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage`? I would check if both resides on the same package.

I bet if you have changed the secondPage name to `com.example.EZEE.SecondPage` it will work.

if it didn't work I would remove the `android:name` of both activity and within the "", click `ctrl + space` and let the eclipse handle putting the naming to the activity. therefore the shown activities are guaranteed to work in the application.

Hope this works with you, please give me a feedback.

Comment: Yes, I have both "com.example.EZEE.MainActivity"  and "com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage"  under the same Package named: EZEE. So in my package explorer i see.                                              EZEE --> src --> com.example.EZEE and src --> com.wwes.EZEE

Comment: Ok now what i have done is moved the MainActivity.java file under "com.wwes.EZEE" and removed it from "com.example.EZEE"

Comment: by doing so, is the application launching?

Comment: I believe you should move the `SecondPage.java` to `com.example.EZEE` and change the manifest to `android:name:com.example.EZEE.SecondPage`

Comment: Yes, the application launches, I see the spalsh Scree Image, but ends with an ERROR on phone " The application now has to close and exits"

Comment: I will try now. Someone here suggested to move MainActivity.java to "com.wwes.EZEE" & made appropriate changes in manifest.xml but failed with same error: ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.wwes.EZEE/com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage

Comment: Ok now my "com.example.EZEE" has both files: MainActivity.java and SecondPage.java. So in my manifest.xml, now I should only have "android:name:com.example.EZEE.SecondPage" activity and remove the other SeconPage activity, correct?

Comment: ya you should only have 2 activities with the name of: `android:name:com.example.EZEE.MainActivity` and `android:name:com.example.EZEE.SecondPage`

Comment: BTW, even if i were to move the other way around.i.e both the .java files into "com.wwes.EZEE", it should work, isnt it?

Comment: no i dont think so because you are moving both files to package -> package. not to the main package

Comment: Thanks. But moving both files to "com.wwes.EZEE" doesnt work. Still same FATAL EXCEPTION error, consistently pointing to if [com.wwes.EZEE/com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage} has been defined in manifext.xml or not... Its mind-boggling as to whats going wrong here .... :-(

Comment: I told you to move them both to `com.example.EZEE`

Comment: I now have a problem starting Eclipse.. Earlier i ran in DEBUG mode and after debugging just shut it. Now whenever i open eclipse, by default it opens in DEBUG ADT mode and goes in to NOT responding state.. waited for 30mins after opening eclipse but cant proceed. would u know how to get past this? Thnks alot for ur help

Comment: Ok i have now sorted out the Eclipse startup problem.. Now will make changes as you suggested, will run & update you ...

Comment: Ok, I moved both files to: com.example.EZEE. I now have 6 errors, pointing to "R cannot be resolved to a variable".. one of them is pointing to : setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_page);

Comment: Hi Coderji- Finally I have something working. I created a complete fresh project & now i only have 1 -single package consisting of those 2 java files. Now, the Splash-screen image loads and then it goes to the second-page activity. However, in the webview doesn't open, its just a blank-white-screen. On the logcat, I see the ERROR: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length. Any ideas on solving this?

Comment: glad I was able to help, I have never passed this issue before but after googling it, I dont think it is related to webview. refer to the is [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length) hope it can help you out

Comment: Yes, thanks I read that thread which internally had some more weblinks to read & figured out that its not a problem in the code but inside android native code-base.

Answer (score 10):

you must defin your activity in manifest.xml file

```
 <activity  android:name=".SecondPage"
          android:label="@string/title_activity_second_page" >

</activity>
```

Comment: Please see above. My manifest.xml already has the definition of the activity.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `<intent-filter>` tag in the SecondPage tag of the manifest because you are already starting the activity from `MainActivity`.

So, remove this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

from this:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_second_page" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion of removing the <intent-filter>. Doesn't work. I get same error.

Comment: Can you post the **entire** manifest.xml? (I mean from manifest start tag to manifest end tag)

Comment: Remove `package="com.wwes.EZEE"` from the `manifest` tag at the top

Comment: Now it gives the following error at line# (<?xml version="1.0".....: AndroidManifest.xml does not declare a Java Package: Build aborted

Comment: Then I guess you need to have `MainActivity` and `SecondPage` both in either `com.example.EZEE` or `com.wwes.EZEE`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your defination of **.SecondPage** to the following in **manifest.xml** file

```
 <activity  android:name="com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage"
              android:label="@string/title_activity_second_page" >

    </activity>
```

Comment: See above. I already have exact same definition in my manifest.xml file.

Comment: Delete the <intent-filter> part or change it to <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> </intent-filter>

Comment: I have already tried deleting the <intent-filter> but see same error.

Comment: I can see that your updated manifest.xml still contain the <intent-filter> tag while defining the second page!!???

Comment: its removed in my project but was mistakenly here in the post. I have now removed it from post also

Comment: ok.Now if you are getting the same error i can suggest you one thing.Pull your MainActivity from the package com.example.EZEE to the package com.wwes.EZEE;and then change the definition of MainActivity in manifest as:    android:name="com.wwes.EZEE.MainActivity"

Comment: Ok I just moved the public class Mainactivity extends Activty {//} to SecondPage.java It gives me error telling "Public type mainActivity" must be defined in its own file

Comment: nono you are getting me wrong.According to you code you have must have two packages:com.example.EZEE and com.wwes.EZEE;I am just telling to move MainActivity class to the later package.And then please delete the MainActivity within com.example.EZEE package

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I have just moved the MainActivity class from com.example.EZEE to com.wwes.EZEE. What about the run(), onCreate() and OncreateOptionsMenu() functions, I cant retain them in mainActivity.java, correct? So what code will my MainActivity.java file have?

Comment: You do not need to worry about them.Just rt click on MainActivity->copy and paste it in your  com.wwes.EZEE; package.Remove the mainactivity from the older one.and dont forget to update manifest as: android:name="com.wwes.EZEE.MainActivity" .It should work.

Comment: In manifest.xml, i made following change to:                           <activity android:name="com.wwes.EZEE.MainActivity" Still same error of: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.wwes.EZEE/com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage}; have you declared this activity in your Manifext.xml

Comment: it seems that Everything is now perfect.Clean your project and run.

Comment: I did Project --> Clean and re-ran directly to test on the samsung phone.. Same error Unable to find explicit activity class {com.wwes.EZEE/com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage}  :-(                             BTW, in manifest.xml, I have the following intact: android:name=".SecondPage"  android:label="@string/title_activity_second_page">

Comment: Please see above, updated line added to manifest.xml as ////UPDATED //// Rest of the file is the same.

Comment: Why should the package name be updated? Shouldn't it remain as:        package="com.wwes.EZEE"?

Comment: I am talking about the first line in your mainactivity class.Is it  package com.wwes.EZEE??

Comment: Yes, thats correct. ist few lines of my MainActivity.java are:   package  com.wwes.EZEE;                                               import com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage;                                        import com.wwes.EZEE.R;

Comment: Remove  import com.wwes.EZEE.R;

Comment: removed it an ran on Samsung phone Same error: FATAL EXCEPTION pointing to have you declared this activity in manifest.xml as {com.wwes.EZEE/com.wwes.EZEE.SecondPage}. I wonder whats going wrong?

Comment: Do you know how to debug??then put a breakpoing in the button and debug it.There must be some silly mistake.

Comment: No. Not really. But definitely some very obvious mistake, I cant seem to catch...BTW when i ran in debug-mode (i.e: debug) on my phone, it didnt crash. But it didnt even proceed ahead of the Splash Screen.

Comment: hi kgandroid- moving files to com.wwes.EZEE did'nt work. but yes, if move them to com.example.EZEE started working. I anyways had lots of issues related to R could not be resolved. Hence, i created fresh project & had only 1-package this time with those 2 files & now it works fine. Ofcoz, there are some cosmetic glitches like white-screen etc but now it works. Thanks

Comment: yahh...thats the main thing...moving two files in one package.