# Getting the error never saw before from my button Android

Tags: android, html, xml

I got an error from my button click that I have never seen before. It shows up after i button click.

[image]

**code:**

```
public class RegisterUser extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText dispName;
EditText emailAddr;
EditText passwd;
EditText rl_name;
Button reg_btn;
Spinner ctry_spinner;
String choice;
ImageButton go_back;
Boolean check_email_exit = false;
TextView set_fail;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
    dispName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uid);
    emailAddr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_add);
    passwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);
    set_fail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fail_text);
    ctry_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country_sel);
    reg_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_up_btn);
    reg_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

       //language selection list    
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.country_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ctry_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    ctry_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
           choice =  ctry_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        };

    });

    go_back = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.go_back);
    go_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent toStart_appActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), start_appActivity.class);
            startActivity(toStart_appActivity);
        }
        });     

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.sign_up_btn:
        String email = emailAddr.getText().toString().trim();
        String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
        if(dispName.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            set_fail.setText("Enter display name to be shown"); 
            }
        else if(emailAddr.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            set_fail.setText("Enter your email address"); 
            }
        else if(passwd.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){
            set_fail.setText("Enter your login password"); 
        }
        else if(passwd.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0){
            int pwlength = passwd.getText().length();
            if(pwlength < 6){
                set_fail.setText("Your password must contain 6 characters or more"); 
            }
        }
        else{
            // onClick of button perform this simplest code.
            System.out.print("1 break");
            if (email.matches(emailPattern))
            {
                set_fail.setText("Valid email address");
                set_fail.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
                System.out.print("first break");
                check_mail_exist(emailAddr.getText().toString());
                System.out.print("third break");
            }
            else 
            {
                set_fail.setText("Invalid email address");
                set_fail.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3300"));
            }

        }
    break;
}

}

private void check_mail_exist(final String ent_email) {

Firebase f_user = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/User/");
f_user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap_user) {
        System.out.print("second break");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> rs = snap_user.getChildren();
        Iterator<DataSnapshot> irs = rs.iterator();
        long allNum2 = snap_user.getChildrenCount();
        int maxNum2 = (int)allNum2;
        int count_user = 1;
        while(irs.hasNext())
        {
            if(count_user <= maxNum2)
            {
                Map<String, Object> nPost = (Map<String, Object>) irs.next().getValue();
                String db_email = nPost.get("email_addr").toString();

                    if(ent_email.equals(db_email))
                    {
                        set_fail.setText("This email has already exist!");
                        set_fail.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3300"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Firebase f = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/"); 
                        Firebase userData = f.child("User");
                        //save into login & auth of email and password SUCCESS
                        //create custom email and password for this app using Firebase as host.
                        userData.createUser(emailAddr.getText().toString(), passwd.getText().toString(), new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
                                System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                                // there was an error
                            }
                        });

                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                        String today_date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

                        Firebase set_user = userData.push();
                        String user_id = set_user.getKey();

                        Map<String, Object> save_user = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        save_user.put("disp_name", dispName.getText().toString());
                        save_user.put("real_name", "");
                        save_user.put("dob", "");
                        save_user.put("date_created", today_date);
                        save_user.put("userDesc", "");
                        save_user.put("email_addr", emailAddr.getText().toString());
                        save_user.put("user_pwd", passwd.getText().toString());
                        save_user.put("lastProfChange", "");
                        save_user.put("country", choice);
                        save_user.put("id",user_id);
                        set_user.setValue(save_user);

                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registration success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                            ;                   
                        Intent toStartupActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), start_appActivity.class);
                        startActivity(toStartupActivity);   
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed");
                }
            count_user++;
        }                       
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});                         

 }


}
```

Here is my **XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/regbg"
>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/title_register"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >  

  <TextView
 android:id="@+id/regi_title"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ems="10" 
 android:text="Registration"
 android:textSize="30dp"
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:textStyle="bold">
 </TextView>

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/up"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/round_edges_layout"> 


 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/editText2"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ems="10" 
 android:text="Email"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:textStyle="bold">
 </TextView>

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/email_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:hint="Email" />
   <View
   android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"/>  

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/editText3"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ems="10" 
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:text="Password"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:textStyle="bold">
   </TextView>

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/pwd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword|textNoSuggestions"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:hint="Password" />
   <View
   android:layout_width="280dp"
   android:layout_height="2dp"
   android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/editText4"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ems="10" 
 android:text="Display Name"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:textStyle="bold">
</TextView>

<EditText
 android:id="@+id/uid"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ems="10"
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
 android:hint="Display Name" />

 <View
  android:layout_width="280dp"
  android:layout_height="2dp"
  android:background="#c0c0c0"/> 

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/editText5"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ems="10" 
 android:text="Country selection"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:textStyle="bold">
</TextView>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/country_sel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linere"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/fail_text"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ems="10" 
 android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
 android:textColor="#FF1919"
 android:textStyle="bold">
 </TextView>  

  </LinearLayout> 
  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="120dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_up_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@drawable/btn_text_click"
    android:background="@drawable/greenbtn"
    android:text="Confirm" />         
   </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal" 
 android:layout_below="@+id/up"
 android:layout_marginLeft="258dp">

<ImageButton
 android:id="@+id/go_back"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/back_btn" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This happened when I click the sign_up_btn. I tried the keyboard changes but they do not work, I am not sure what is wrong because it was working just before I hand this up to my supervisor and now its not working.

Getting the following **ERROR** also....

[image]
Any information will help thanks.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length

Comment: And please post the actual error in the future instead of a screenshot. They can get really hard to read that way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18195302/4150528 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/16398294/4150528 --- very good links

Comment: they dont work. it was working before and now it happens right after I gave my supervisor the project. I spent 34 sleepless hour :s

Comment: Do you have an EditText in your layout?

Comment: I added the xml and full code, the problem lies with the button click

Comment: none of the system prints would work when click sign_up click.

Comment: I faced this Error in my app, when user clear a search EditText (empty text), this is why i'm asking about the EditText... in my case, adding `android:inputType="text"` to my EditText fixed the problem.

Comment: sorry which edit text are you using this on?

Comment: i think my error lies with the following added error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the error and it shouldn't be an error. My if password length is less 6 characters caused the error. But it shouldn't because it should be skipped when the user enter greater than 6 characters and button click the second time. Anyone can provide some insight?