# Error on windows open

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have this simple code:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
     title: 'aaa',
     width: '100%',
     height: '100%',
     backgroundColor: '#eff2d8'
 });
 win.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT];
 win.open();
```

After the command Win.open I got this error:

SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Is this all your code ?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you are using 3rd party keyboard instead of the native phone keyboard. This often happens with SwiftKey.

[Android - SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length)

Comment: I'm using a Samsung GT-I9300, Android version 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Make it more simple

```
 var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
     title: 'aaa',
     width: Ti.UI.FILL,
     height: Ti.UI.FILL,
     backgroundColor: '#eff2d8'
 });
 win.open();
```

Does this work for you?