# Flutter - spans cannot have a zero length

Tags: android, spannablestring, flutter

I am developping a Flutter app which uses a `Textfield`.

I am declaring the `TextField` like this :

```dart
new TextField(
  controller : _controller,
  decoration : new InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Message...'
  )
)
```

The `TextField` is displayed in my widget, however when I tap on it, the keyboard is automatically closed and the following error appears in the console

```
E/SpannableStringBuilder(17860): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

I am running this using the Flutter plugin in IntelliJ on a Android (Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime, Android 5.1).

How could I solve this problem ?

**EDIT**: As seen on this answer ([Android - SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length)), I have tried switching keyboard (Google and Samsung), stille the same

Comment: How are you initializing _controller?

Comment: final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

Comment: As showned here : https://flutter.io/text-input/

Answer (score 3):

The fix for me was to add `autocorrect: false`, and set `keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword` the bug occurred on my s8plus, it didn't happen on my iPhone simulator.

```
return TextFormField(
        controller: emailController,
        autofocus: true,
        autocorrect: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
        validator: validateEmailOrPhoneNumber,
        onChanged: (text) {
          this._validateEmailORPhoneNumber(text);
          this._onTouched('emailOrPhoneNumber');
        },
        onTap: () => _onTouched('emailOrPhoneNumber'),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: isPhoneNumber
                ? Container(
                    width: 70,
                    child: leftSection,
            )
                : null,
            labelText: 'Email or Phone number',
            hintText: 'Enter Email or Phone number'),
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the full error might be somewhere else. I would suggest opening a new flutter issue if the issue is specific to one android device.

Comment: Will try with another android device, I will keep you in touch

Comment: Just tried with a Galxy Tab A and doesn't get the bug. Will open an issue. Thanks collin

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. In my case, the problem wasn't the `TextFormField`. It was because of the key inside the `Form` widget. If you use a key, the general widget must be `StatefulWidget`, not `StatelessWidget`.

## Wrong code

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: TextFormField(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Right Code

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyWidgetState();
  }
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget>{
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: TextFormField(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```