# LoginManager doesn't respond after 3 logins

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

My problem is that after two log ins with facebook, login manager doesn't respond. I mean I can log in and log out two times, but after only facebook spinner appears and nothing happens. I tried to find out where is the problem, and I think that when I'm trying to register a callback for login manager it doesn't get a response. No one function will be called ( onSucces,onCancel,onError ).

**Facebook login**

```
 private void facebookLogin()
    {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LogInActivity.this, Arrays.asList("email"));
        Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this,"asd0000",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this,"asd2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this,"asd11",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this,"Log in was canceled!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this,"Error" + error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I initialize callback manager in onCreate.

**Errors**

```
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zerolength
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length

Comment: @JayRathodRJ That error appears because i'm using swift keyboard instead of google's, but the main issue is that I can't log in with facebook after 2 tries and my debugger is empty I don't get an error. As I said before I tried to find out very is the problem and how i saw when I register a callback for loginmanager no function is called after, and I hoped that someone can explain what should I do