# Android checking a EditText text from a TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to validate some EditText with a TextWathcher as follows:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            boolean ServerOK = false;
            boolean NameOK = false;
            boolean EmpidOK = false;
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String txtName = txtEmployeeName.getText().toString();
                String txtEmpid = txtEmployeeID.getText().toString();
                if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(txtServerName.getText().toString()))
                {
                    ServerOK = true;
                }

                // Name input is fine
                if(txtName.length() > -1) {
                    NameOK = true;
                }

                // Employee ID input is fine
                if(txtEmpid.length() > -1) {
                    EmpidOK = true;
                }

                // Validate both fields and activate button if all OK
                if (NameOK && ServerOK && EmpidOK) {
                    btnRegister.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    btnRegister.setEnabled(false);
                }
                System.out.println(NameOK + " " + EmpidOK + " " + ServerOK);
            }
        };
        txtEmployeeName.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        txtServerName.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        txtEmployeeID.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
 }
```

The issue is that when typing in some text in the EdiText the booleans are set correctly. If I delete any of the strings in the TexViews as soon as I hit 0 characters in the EditText:

```
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. How come a person can type over TextView?

Comment: what your doing inside this method ? URLUtil.isValidUrl(

Comment: @Adul Waheed Sorry!! My mistake edited the question

Comment: Are you using the swiftkeyboard? Because I happen to come across this type of error in logcat when I was using it. If yes then change it to Default keyboard.

Comment: @KingofMasses I am checking if the URL is a valid one

Comment: @RudrikPatel I am using the emulator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length

Comment: android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
Try to set this inside the xml properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            btnRegister.setEnabled(!txtEmployeeName.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !txtEmployeeID.getText().toString().isEmpty()&&URLUtil.isValidUrl(txtServerName.getText().toString()));
        }
    };
```

don't forgot to add `btnRegister.setEnabled(false);` in on create

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Try to set above property inside the Edit text view along with using a default keyboard.

Comment: Tried but with same result

Answer (score 0):

I am using this library: https://github.com/pawegio/KAndroid

example:

```
passwordEditText.textWatcher {
            afterTextChanged {
                ...
            }
        }
```

It is very simple to use