# Put method of Retrofit is not working in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to implement a put method using Retrofit2 to update records of a demo API, but it's not giving me response in callback and jump into onFailure function.

- I'm using demo APi (http://dummy.restapiexample.com/update)
- I have a response class UpdateResponse
- I have a Api class and a ApiInterface
- and a dialog box instead of main activity
- there is one @path (id) and three @fields(name,salary,age) using PUT method in ApiInterface

UpdateResponse class code is below

```
public class UpdateResponse {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("salary")
@Expose
private String salary;
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private String age;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String employeeName) {
    this.name = employeeName;
}

public String getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(String employeeSalary) {
    this.salary = employeeSalary;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String employeeAge) {
    this.age = employeeAge;
}
}
```

Api Interface code is below

```
public interface ApiInterface {


@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT("api/v1/update/{id}")
Call<UpdateResponse> updateUser(@Path("id") int id,
                                  @Field("name") String name,
                                  @Field("salary") String salary,
                                  @Field("age") String age);

}
```

Api Class code is below

```
public class Api {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static ApiInterface getClient() {


    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    ApiInterface api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    return api;
}

}
```

And Dialog box as main activity code is below

```
                String nameStr = name.getText().toString();
                String salaryStr = salary.getText().toString();
                String ageStr = age.getText().toString();
                //idd is getting from mainActivity onitemSelect method, which is having the right id value

               Call<UpdateResponse> call= Api.getClient().updateUser(idd,nameStr,salaryStr,ageStr);
               call.enqueue(new Callback<UpdateResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<UpdateResponse> call, Response<UpdateResponse> response) {
                        Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(),"Updated Name: "+response.body().getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<UpdateResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(),"Failure",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

In response call it's showing:

> call: ExecuterCallAdapterFactory$ExecuterCallbackCall@5922" and in Throwable t it showing like "com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 27 path $.error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - SPAN\_EXCLUSIVE\_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670374/android-span-exclusive-exclusive-spans-cannot-have-a-zero-length)

Comment: No Radesh, its not the solution of my problem, please have a look at the end of the question, i had some edits

Comment: Looks like your response json is not matching your UpdateResponse structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to send a json body

Change your api method signature like below

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
@PUT("api/v1/update/{id}")
Call<ResponseBody> updateUser(@Path("id") int id, @Body UpdateResponse body);
```

Make id [transient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3)

```
public class UpdateResponse {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private transient int id;
    //..
```

Pass data in the body

```
 UpdateResponse updateResponse = new UpdateResponse();
 updateResponse.setName(name.getText().toString());
 updateResponse.setSalary(salary.getText().toString());
 updateResponse.setAge(age.getText().toString());

 Call<UpdateResponse> call= Api.getClient().updateUser(idd, updateResponse);
```

Comment: thank you very much,it worked...once again a huge thanks my friend

Comment: can u please further explain why it was not giving response, so that i....

Comment: You api expects data to be passed in json format. You are sending them as field value.

Comment: It excludes id from being serialized in json body

Comment: u mean we r kind of stopping id so that we need to put three fields except id,m i right or?

Comment: Sorta, yes. it should work even if you dont use transient key on a real api depending on the backend implementation

Comment: yeah its working(on the same API) but why!!! i mean what was the effect of transient then...

Comment: It will work but its always better not to send any unnecessary field to the server. transient in this case excluding  id field from the body.

Comment: okay got it, thank u very much for giving me your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your retrofit code is fine. Could you share the whole Log with the error?  I had a different issue with SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE with related to an EditText.

The errors you are getting are not a result of your code; you probably are testing on a Samsung device that has Samsung's TouchWiz.

I had the same errors, then I tested on a Nexus S (also by Samsung, but pure Android OS without TouchWiz) and I didn't get this error.